# ruby / splitting array into columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I could've found out using the right naming, but so far nothing popped up. I'd look into splitting an array into columns.

Meaning, having `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9]`, I'd like to have 4 arrays (4 columns) :

`[ [0,4,9], [1,5], [2,6], [3,7] ]`

Practically, I'd look into iterating over an active record array, displaying those (they're images records) in 4 different html columns, while maintaining their order from left to right

Comment: I think you lost 8 in your result. :)

Comment: Are you concerned only with arrays having nine elements? If not, you'll have to tell us the rule you want implemented?

Comment: @BroiSatse yep indeed (:

Comment: @CarySwoveland not at all

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Rails solution

In rails, you can simply do:

```
ary = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ary.in_groups_of(4).transpose.map(&:compact)
  #=> [[0, 4, 8], [1, 5, 9], [2, 6], [3, 7]]
```

### Explanation:

`in_groups_of` is a cool rails method added to Array class, which behaves very similar to `each_slice`, with the difference being that it guarantees all the arrays to be the same size. It is important here so we can use `transpose` later on. This method returns an array of your rows.

Now, `transpose` - another cool method worth knowing. It expects an array of arrays, and all inner arrays must be the same length (so in fact this represents a rectangular matrix). What it does - it returns an array of columns in target array.

Now we need to get rid of nils (unless they don't bother you), so we run `compact` on each of the columns and we have exactly what you wanted.

### Pure ruby solution:

We don't have `in_groups_of` so we need to implement same behaviour without it:

```
ary.each_slice(4).map {|a| a.fill nil, a.size, 4 - a.size}.transpose.map(&:compact)
```

## Better solution to practical issue

> Practically, I'd look into iterating over an active record array,
>   displaying those (they're images records) in 4 different html columns,
>   while maintaining their order from left to right

You should never use tables to display your data unless it is a tabular data. Images are not tabular data, meaning that the location of that particular image at given column/row is completely irrelevant. There always is a better way to do this.

In your case, I would suggest pure CSS solution (haml):

```
%ul.images
  - @images.each do |i|
    %li= image_tag i.iamge_url    # or sth
```

Then in your css (scss):

```
ul.images {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;    # remove whitespace between li elements
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;   # forcing 25% without whitespaces guarantees 4 column
  }
}
```

Main advantage of this model is that you can make the number of column dependent on media queries, so display different number of images per row depending on your user screen size (important for mobiles).

If you feel more adventurous and you hate IE and don't care for it's users, go and check out flex-boxes as well. One day it might become a standard and can be seen on many pages already.

Comment: I'm unable to get your pure Ruby solution working.  For me your each_slice block is returning nil.

Comment: @6ftDan - Thanks for noticing, fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

I have a short solution :-)

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]

x.group_by.with_index {|_,index| index % 4 }.values
# => [[0, 4, 9], [1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7]]
```

I have posted a blog post on [Ruby: Arrays by Example](http://6ftdan.com/allyourdev/2015/12/12/ruby-arrays-by-example/) for a visual resource.

Comment: I somehow missed your solution before. Very creative!

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
input = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
max_columns = 4
input.each_with_index.with_object([]) do | (val, index), output|
    i = index % max_columns
    (output[i] ||= []).push(val)
end
```

Comment: I suggest you either add the line `output` at the end or, better, delete `output = []` and change the 4th line to  `input.each_with_index.with_object([]) do | (val, index), output|`.

Comment: Changed it to match your suggestion, I did not know about the `with_object` method, seems very useful!

Answer (score 1):

or by slicing your big array into smaller arrays  with [SLICE](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice)

```
input = Array(1 .. 33)

output = input.each_slice(4).to_a

output.each do |x| puts "#{x}" 
end
```

outputs :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
[13, 14, 15, 16]
[17, 18, 19, 20]
[21, 22, 23, 24]
[25, 26, 27, 28]
[29, 30, 31, 32]
[33]
```

fyi , not exactly an array of arrays , but something to look into.

Comment: well as long it remains iteratable… it is an 'array of arrays'

Comment: behind the scene , yes :)

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that if the size of the array is not evenly divided by `4`, the first so-many sliced arrays are to be of the same size and each have one more element than each each of remaining sliced arrays.
Here are a couple ways you could do that.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

**Compute number of arrays having an extra element**

```
def split_it(n, arr)
  std_arr_size, nbr_bonus_arrays = arr.size.divmod(n)
  nbr_bonus_elements = nbr_bonus_arrays * (std_arr_size + 1)
  arr[0...nbr_bonus_elements].each_slice(std_arr_size+1).to_a +
    arr[nbr_bonus_elements..-1].each_slice(std_arr_size).to_a
end

split_it(1, arr)  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]] 
split_it(2, arr)  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]] 
split_it(3, arr)  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] 
split_it(4, arr)  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]  
split_it(5, arr)  #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]] 
split_it(6, arr)  #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7], [8], [9]] 
split_it(7, arr)  #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]] 
split_it(8, arr)  #=> [[1, 2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]] 
split_it(9, arr)  #=> [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
```

**Use recursion**

```
def split_it(n, arr)
  return [arr] if n==1
  m = (arr.size.to_f/n).ceil
  [arr.first(m)] + split_it(n-1, arr[m..-1])
end

split_it(1, arr)  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]] 
split_it(2, arr)  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]] 
split_it(3, arr)  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] 
split_it(4, arr)  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]]  
split_it(5, arr)  #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]] 
split_it(6, arr)  #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7], [8], [9]] 
split_it(7, arr)  #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]] 
split_it(8, arr)  #=> [[1, 2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]] 
split_it(9, arr)  #=> [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure Ruby solution.

```
def split(n, arr)
  arr.each_with_index.reduce(Array.new(n) { [] }) do |a, (e, i)|
    a[i%n] << e
    a
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**: As oneliner as suggested by Cary. It uses `with_object()` instead of `reduce()` and initializes the sub array lazily when used.

```
def split(n, arr)
  arr.each_with_index.with_object([]) { |(e, i), a| (a[i%n] ||= []) << e }
end
```

Comment: You could write it: `arr.each_with_index.with_object([]) { |(e,i),a| (a[i%n] ||= []) << e }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good suggestion. It avoids the additional statement `a` to return the accumulated object when using `reduce()`. Will use it next time.